# Why are unordered python dictionary lookups 10x slower than ordered lookups?

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary, lookup

I try to make fast dictionary lookups in python by iterating a list of integers. I noticed that unordered lookups are approximately 10x slower than ordered ones.

Is there any way to speed up unordered dictionary lookups? Do you know any reason for the time differences? In my original data, the entries are not ordered or consecutive because not all integers within a range are in my list.

**What I did:**

```
dummy_dict = {i:i for i in range(10000000)}

#Ordered list
a = [i for i in range(10000000)] 

#Unordered list
b = [i for i in range(10000000)] 
random.shuffle(b)

#Sorted unordered list
c = b[:]
c.sort()
```

The times for runs:

```
[dummy_dict[i] for i in a] #Time to run: 0.7s
[dummy_dict[i] for i in b] #Time to run: 6.7s
[dummy_dict[i] for i in c] #Time to run: 0.7s
```

Not only is it slower to make dictionary lookups but also the time for just iterating the lists is different:

```
["" for i in a] #Time to run: 0.3s
["" for i in b] #Time to run: 0.9s
["" for i in c] #Time to run: 0.3s
```

To further increase my confusion, if I create a random list like this:

```
#Random list
e = [random.randint(0,9999999) for i in range(10000000)]
```

Then the time to iterate the list does not increase:

```
["" for i in e] #Time to run: 0.3s
```

But the dictionary lookups are again slow:

```
[dummy_dict[i] for i in e] #Time to run: 6.3s
```

Comment: This is due to memory locality in the dictionary. Nearby keys are close to each other in the memory of the dictionary, so there are fewer cache misses.

Comment: Does this happen if you create the dictionary in a random order?

Comment: The tests with `dummy_dict` exacerbate the results but I can still reproduce the timing difference using the simpler example: `[0 for i in b]` runs about 3x slower than `[0 for i in a]`

Comment: @Barmar When I create the dictionary randomly, the difference mitigates so that on my computer the difference is only 3x. I guess at least the memory locality is behind this. If so, it might be difficult to speed up the dictionary lookups.

Comment: I believe `[0 for i in b]` is slower than `[0 for i in a]` because objects in `a` list are stored in memory *in-order* (try to `print([id(i) for i in a[-5:]])`) and objects in `b` list are shuffled. So accessing the objects in `b` might thrash the cpu cache. With `e = [random.randint(0,9999999) for i in range(10000000)]` you create objects of type `int` *in-order* again (but with random values).

Answer (score 5):

The slower execution is due to two combined effects. The problem mainly comes from the **memory access pattern of the internal data structure**.

> the time for just iterating the lists is different

This is because Python lists do not actually contain integers but **reference** to integer objects. Thus, when you create the list `b`, CPython allocates 10_000_000 items and adds a reference in the list which is basically the low-level address of the object in memory. Allocated objects tends to be close to each other because of the way the internal allocator works (they are typically put one after the other). The thing is `random.shuffle` does not copy the object or create new ones, **it just shuffles the list and so the reference, not the object in memory**.

The thing is **accessing data from memory using a random access pattern is much slower than contiguous data**. This problem is called *memory diffusion*. This is why some application are getting slower over time. Some runtime can move object in memory so to make access fast (AFAIK, some JVM in Java does that but not CPython -- PyPy [may do that](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/gc_info.html) except for big objects).

You can check this effect by just creating a new list: `d = [(i+1)-1 for i in b]` from the shuffled `b` list and do the benchmark with `d` (spoil: it is faster on my machine and actually as fast as `c`).

Note that, in practice, the dictionary might not be filled all at once in a real-world application.

> I noticed that unordered lookups are approximately 10x slower than ordered ones.

This is because dictionaries are designed to be ordered internally and so accessing them in an ordered way cause a much **more predictable** memory access pattern. Modern processors can efficiently **prefetch data from memory** when the access is predictable. Moreover, when not all objects can fit in the cache and the memory accesses are random, many **cache lines are less reused** (if any) because cache lines are **evicted from the cache** due to new cache lines being loaded for the new objects. In practice, this is even worst because cache are not fully associative. The resulting effect is called **cache trashing**. This effect is not really an issue when many objects share the same cache line.

> Is there any way to speed up unordered dictionary lookups?

The usual solution is to re-order the data structure or to simply create a new copy while considering the traversal ordering (like for the `d` list before). In general, dictionary lookup are not very efficient because hashing tends to shuffle memory accesses. This is also what makes them asymptotically fast though (`O(1)` lookups).

In lower-level native languages (like C), you can use manual software prefetching so to significantly reduce the latency of dictionary lookups (this is not flexible/portable and a bit tricky to do in practice though). This is not possible in a high-level language like Python.

Comment: I'm reminded of one of the major insights making Clojure's STM feasible in practice (from an efficiency perspective) being around cache line effects being visible even through the JVM, which a lot of folks were accustomed to considering as a black box it wasn't necessary to think past.

Comment: Thank you Jérome for the comprehensive answer, this was very useful. Based on the idea that hashing with dictionaries shuffle memory access or may for other reasons be inefficient, I tried replaced the  `dummy_dict` for `dummy_list = [i for i in range(10000000)]` and made lookups with  `[dummy_list[i] for i in e]` which was around 40% faster than `[dummy_dict[i] for i in e]`. Although not sure yet if this will scale as the numbers in my original dict are not consecutive either.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Jérôme Richard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75597536/8451814), the references to the underlying `int` objects are what are being shuffled. Iterating through the references themselves is cache friendly but accessing the underlying object is not:

```py
> list(map(lambda x: id(x)-id(a[0]), a[:10]))
[0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 288]

> list(map(lambda x: id(x)-id(b[0]), b[:10]))
[0,
 13489216,
 151516672,
 -3041184,
 -1031616,
 148789760,
 146240,
 14147072,
 14160448,
 11196608]

> list(map(lambda x: id(x)-id(c[0]), c[:10]))
[0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 288]
```

Note that CPython's implementation of `id` returns the object's memory address so we can see that `b`'s contents are not stored sequentially in memory.

IMO the `dummy_dict` tests introduce confounding factors and should be ignored as the real culprit is the non-continuous storage of the underlying `int` objects. Here's the test code without the `dict` influence:

```py
N = 1000000

#Ordered list
a = [i for i in range(N)]

#Unordered list
b = [i for i in range(N)]
random.shuffle(b)

#Sorted unordered list
c = b[:]
c.sort()

print(timeit.timeit('[0 for _ in a]', number=100, globals=locals()))
print(timeit.timeit('[0 for _ in b]', number=100, globals=locals()))
print(timeit.timeit('[0 for _ in c]', number=100, globals=locals()))


1.4839237749110907
5.085452176863328
1.397052046842873
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Great representation that the references are being shuffled in the case of `b`. However, this is not the case for `e` where the dictionary lookups were also slow. Also, the real bottleneck seem to be making the dictionary lookups and not iterating and accessing the int objects from the list.